# How to connect VPS to MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb

I bought a VPS and I want to put MongoDB server there. I connect to VPS with ssh tunnel, install MongoDB and start it.
The question is, that how can I add VPS server to MongoDB Compass? Is it even possible?

I was trying to connect via hostname but I receive this error - `connect ECONNREFUSED my.ip.adress.here`
Also was trying to connect via ssh tunnel in MongoDB Compass - doesn't work for me.

Maybe there is a problem with port?

I can connect to my VPS from terminal with ssh.

**Edit1:**
I was using this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to install MongoDB on ubuntu and I'm using MongoDB 4.2.8

**EDIT2:** When I install mongodb on VPS, MongoDB ip is 127.0.0.1 how can I change it? I want it to set it for VPS ip address. If it's possible, otherwise I don't understand how I can connect to my DB on VPS.

Sorry if it's lame questions, just first time using VPS and it's pretty complex to me.

Comment: How did you configure the mongod when you started it?  What version of MonogDB are you trying to use?

Comment: @Joe Hey! Thanks for answer, I update main question.

Comment: Which port database run? Did you checked firewall on VPS? try `telnet  ip.address database_port` on local computer to verify whether port is accessible.

Comment: The default in mongodb 4.2 is to bind only to 127.0.0.1, did you change that?

Comment: @Joe, no I hadn't I also discover that on VPN my mongo ip is localhost ip. Is that IP Binding documentation to change ip adress, I'm a righT?

Comment: @Salitha it says to me that connection is refused accordingly to your method

Comment: Either mongo server is not running or VPS firewall is blocking the port. First, check firewall config and allow the port. (both from server and VPS provider as services like google compute engine has their own firewall). `sudo ufw status verbose` will show some info about ubuntu firewall.  check mongodb status with `service mongod status`. If the server running, try `telnet  localhost 27017` on VPS to verify port is correct. Then try `telnet  ip.address database_port` on local computer again to check access.

Comment: @Salitha I just updated the main question and I will try to do your steps as well now. I will inform when I have something

Comment: @Salitha I trying your method, mongod status is running, telnet on local computer says to me that connection refused unable to connect to remote host

Comment: for edit 2, your VPS IP **IS** your mongo IP. I think your firewall is blocking access. first, run `sudo ufw disable` on VPS to disable firewall. Assuming you are using google compute engine, goto compute engine > click on instance > on Network interfaces, click view details > goto firewall > create firewall rule > set target all instances and Protocols and ports to allow all. Then try `telnet vps_ip 27017` on local computer. _Please note that do it on your risk and i'm **not** responsible for any consequences._

Answer (score 7):

Before you can connect to vps with mongodb compass, you need to allow remote connections to mongodb from your vps.

1. It is recommended to secure your mongodb connection with a username and password
2. Edit the mongod.conf file located at

> sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf

3. Enter a comma and append the IP address of the vps to the end of the bindIp field. This will allow remote connections to the mongodb instance
4. Save the file and restart the mongodb connection

> sudo systemctl restart mongod

5. Setup the firewall to allow connections to port 27017 (the default mongodb port) from anywhere. (Please note that will expose your mongo database to the internet. Therefore it is recommended to close this port when shipping to production)

> sudo ufw allow 27017

That's it for the vps.

1. You can now open up mongodb compass
2. Choose "fill in connection fields individually"
3. Fill in the hostname with the IP address of your vps, port is the port which you opened previously 27017 in this case and select authentication by username and password.
4. Enter the username and password of the mongodb admin which you should have created already.
5. Choose the authentication database (usually admin)

That's it. You should be connected. You can now view the collections and fields of your mongodb instance on your remote machine